# how to convert a form data that contains image files to json file using in python django and i am not using django restframe work just python&django

Tags: python, django

```
@csrf_exempt
def registerSeller(request):
    print(request.body)
    data = json.loads(request.body.decode('utf-8'))
```

i am new for django and trying to build api with out django restframework and this is the output for request.body but it gives me error

```
AttributeError: 'bytes' object has no attribute 'read'

request.body 

b'-----------------------------344288735834045826241553250616\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name="username"\r\n\r\nabe7\r\n-----------------------------344288735834045826241553250616\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name="password"\r\n\r\n123\r\n-----------------------------344288735834045826241553250616\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name="phonenumber"\r\n\r\n091010101\r\n-----------------------------344288735834045826241553250616\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name="email"\r\n\r\nemail@gmial.com\r\n-----------------------------344288735834045826241553250616\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name="shop_description"\r\n\r\ndescription new\r\n-----------------------------344288735834045826241553250616\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name="shop_name"\r\n\r\nname new\r\n-----------------------------344288735834045826241553250616\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name="images"\r\n\r\n[object File],[object File],[object File]\r\n-----------------------------344288735834045826241553250616--\r\n'
```

Answer (score 1):

You're getting [multipart form data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4526273/what-does-enctype-multipart-form-data-mean), not JSON data. You could access that with `request.POST` and `request.FILES`.

If you want something that can accept both that and JSON data, you would need to look at the `Content-type` request header and parse the data as JSON only if the content type is something like `application/json`.

Comment: thanks a lot. i can get the data with request.POST and request.FILES like i was having a headache.